# Is this a multivariate regression problem or separate univariate regression problem?

Tags: compositional-data

I have data on the percentage of their 24h day that animals spend doing certain activies.

One response for one animal may look like

30 % spent hunting

30 % spent sleeping

30 % spent eating

10 % spent mating

And then of course we have many covariates. Our interest lies in measuring the effect of these covariates on these percentages.

This is a **compositional data set.** The data sums to 100 %. It is usually analysed using log-ratios. This is a **multi-variate** problem.

**Question:**  .... Can it reasonably be analysed as separate univariate regressions?

Each component has a perfectly sensible independent meaning which is not bemuddled by the correlation structure. If an animal's first component has a 30 % response, then that tells us directly that this animal spent 30 % of a 24h day hunting.

Similar, the last component tells us what percentage of a 24hday the animal spent mating. This too makes sense in isolation.

So, can this data set reasonably be studied by applying, say, 4 separate univariate regressions?

What do you say?